# How can I run jbehave tests with different parameters

Tags: junit, jbehave, test-runner

I have a running test project with jbehave which tests a software on an other machine.

So my problem is, I would like to run the same stories for the same software on an other machines.

When I summarize, the web application I'm testing is installed on 20 different hosts and I would like to run the tests for every instance.

The tests are simple smoke-test, where I daily check some installation, application and database issues.

The test project was configured for one instance and works properly, so I want to extend it for n instances.

Can I parameterize the Testrunner oder something like this? Or can I call the tests many time with different parameters?

I'm little bit confused

Answer (score 0):

you could use parameterized scenario to run the same tests with different parameters

see: http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/parametrised-scenarios.html

Comment: Is there a way of doing it without Examples? I have similar problem with OP, but I a) don't like adding Examples after each Scenario and b) some of my scenarios are already parametrized